# Replace past values of a dataframe column to one from latest period

Tags: python, pandas

hope you can help me

I am working with some timeseries data which shows sales from different retail outlets. I have created a column in my pandas dataframe to show the contribution of of a particular outlet in the total sales for each period. Then, based on that share I classified the outlets by contribution (small, medium, large). Obviously the class could change from period to period.

For some of my analysis, I would like to view aggregated periods, so for the outlet class I would like to refer to the value of the last period. To do this I need to figure out a way to replace the old values with the latest one.

I tried to delete the old values based on .loc (any row which was from an older period) and the combine GroupBy(period).apply and interpolate the missing values from old periods based on latest value which is still there. However it is not working...

Any ideas how I could work around this?
1.

Comment: Can you show us a sample input dataframe and expected result

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am trying to copy paste from excel but it wont format properly. How could I do that?